# Common Gui Using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have one question with Jenkins?..
How can we create a Common Gui by using Jenkins for jobs, i tried searching in google it showed very few results with confusing results pipeline or some other plugin to achieve this ?..

```
https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/top-10-jenkins-featuresplugins/
```

please provide your thoughts on This ,I will be monitoring this thread Actively !.

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify what you mean before anyone can answer this, and I kind of suspect that you're asking a question that is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  What does your link have to do with your question?  What is it you're actually trying to accomplish?  What's a "Common Gui"?

Comment: A user interface that shows all the jobs in one common page ?..